# Cannot read property 'pack' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use d3.js (latest version - v4). In v3 it is work. I have read documantation about layout.pack. Where is my mistake?

```
var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
    .sort(null)
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .padding(2);
```

Comment: It's `d3.pack()`. Drop the "layout".

Comment: Thanks! It's work. Can I mark this comment like answer? @GerardoFurtado

Comment: You can write yourself an answer, and accept it in a couple of days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the "layout". Thanks to @GerardoFurtado

```
var bubble = d3.pack()
    .sort(null)
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .padding(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the newer versions `d3.pack()` doesn't have a `sort` method, so the proper usage for `pack()` with these versions is to call `size` and `padding`, and instead of using sort in here, sort the hierarchy. these are all discussed in here: [Uncaught TypeError: d3.pack(…).sort is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761672/uncaught-typeerror-d3-pack-sort-is-not-a-function)

```
var bubble = d3.pack()
.size([diameter, diameter])
.padding(2);
```