# Uncaught TypeError: d3.pack(...).sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bubble-chart

I am new to Javascript and D3.js and I am currently trying to build a bubble chart in d3.js using an example provided here https://jrue.github.io/coding/2014/exercises/basicbubblepackchart/ and modifying  it according to my assignment. I know that the example above was written in a previous version of d3, and I am using version v4 where syntax has slightly changed,however I am getting a following error when running a program:

**Uncaught TypeError: d3.pack(...).sort is not a function**

```
var diameter = 500, //max size of the bubbles
color    = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10); //color category

var bubble = d3.pack()
.sort()
.size([diameter, diameter])
.padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", diameter)
.attr("height", diameter)
.attr("class", "bubble");

d3.csv("teams.csv", function(error, data){

data = data.map(function(d){ d.value = +d["Amount"]; return d; });

var nodes = bubble.nodes({children:data}).filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

//setup the chart
var bubbles = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .selectAll(".bubble")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter();

bubbles.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d){ return d.r; })
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); });

bubbles.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y + 5; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d){ return d["Team"]; })
    .style({
        "fill":"black", 
        "font-family":"Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, san-serif",
        "font-size": "12px"
    });
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: There is no `sort()` method for `d3.pack()`. You'll have to sort the hierarchy instead.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use the same version of d3 as the author in the example (it looks like you're good by the syntax). Also, it's 'd3.layout.pack().sort(null)'
:)

Comment: Hi,Steven, thanks, but I have d4 installed on my laptop and I want to run my example particularly in this version.. therefore I  dropped "layout' from 'd3.layout.pack' and even I type 'sort.(null)' I am still getting the same error. If  I keep the code same as it is in example I get the following error: Cannot read property 'pack' of undefined

Comment: That's understandable, your error seems to indicate d3 isn't loaded when this bit of JavaScript is running. What are you using to host it? Maybe give me some info on what your set up looks like

Comment: I am using a simple html file and writing a code using a developer mode in Chrome. Here is what I have in my file:<html>
 <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>Hello!</p>
 </body>
</html>   and then I am just using built-in console where I write my code

Comment: It's the setup then, if you're just getting started I'd recommend using [codepen](https://codepen.io/) to get comfortable with javascript and d3. If you really want to do javascript on your own machine you'll need a way to locally host the file [browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/) and [python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-simplehttpserver/) offer simple options

Comment: If OP had a wrong reference to D3, the error would be only `d3 is not defined`. The error clearly shows that D3 is correctly loaded. The problem is that there is no `sort()` method for `d3.pack()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for suggestions. So I am trying to use codepen right now, but when I click run button , nothing happens, I don't see any output of my program...  And I also think  I need to change part of my code where I am parsing data from csv file, since it is on my local machine. How can I read it using codepen?

Comment: I also tried using service repl.it and uploading my code there, but I still get the same error.. Could you explain what can be possibly wrong with this function d3.pack()?

Comment: Try this example, https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269 it uses `d3.v4` which is the version I'm sure you're using.  Also the documentation for `d3.pack()` is [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#pack) and it looks like they did take out the `sort()` function

Comment: Thank you Steven Black and Gerardo Furtado. I found a way to run my code and get the proper output using jsfiddle. And yeah, seems like a lot of things were changed in d3.v4.